# How to declare set with pointer type comparator in C++?

Tags: c++

I have this struct for general lessThan comparison  of pointers:

```
template < class ptype > 
struct lessThan : public binary_function < ptype *, ptype *, bool >
{
    bool operator() (ptype *lhs, ptype *rhs) { return lhs->key() < rhs->key(); }
};
```

Suppose I want to create a set of object pointers using this lessThan comparator. What would be the proper syntax when declaring the set? I'm thinking something like this:

```
set <Object *, lessThan> mySet;
```

or more like a function pointer:

```
set <Object *, lessThan<Object>()> mySet;
```

...but I can't get it to compile. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The template class `std::set` takes as second template argument a type of the concept `Compare`. So in your case the type would be `lessThan<Object>`.

This would make the correct declaration be:

```
std::set<Object*, lessThan<Object>> x;
```

[<kbd>Live demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90dbd37cfd5a415f)

Your first attempt was incorrect because `lessThan` is not a type, it's a class template. Your second attempt was incorrect because `lessThan<Object>()` is a parsed as a function returning `lessThan<Object>`.

Comment: Technically, `lessThan<Object>()` *is* a type. It's just not the right type.

Comment: It's parsed as a type-id there - "function of () returning `lessThan<Object>`".